# Script error 0 while calling jsp page from javascript

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have a jsp Page that i wish to call using JS but i am getting script 0 error, here is the caller JS method

```
function getCustomerNameValues(selectedMarketSegment,selectedCustomerCountry){

    $.post("myjsp.jsp", { attributeName: "attributeValue"},
                                       function(data){
     document.getElementById("CustomizedComboBox").options=data;});
```

My "myjsp.jsp" exist in the same directory as the JSP containing the caller method.

Any suggestions please.

Comment: did you add jquery ?

Comment: yes i did, but still have the same problem